# Is there a function for solving xA=b in opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, linear-regression

I know the function `solve` can solve `Ax=b`. But I want a function to solve xA=b for x?
Is there some function available?

By the way It should work like [mrdivide](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) of Matlab:

```
x = B/A solves the system of linear equations x*A = B for x. The matrices A and B must contain the same number of columns. MATLAB® displays a warning message if A is badly scaled or nearly singular, but performs the calculation regardless.

If A is a scalar, then B/A is equivalent to B./A.

If A is a square n-by-n matrix and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A is a solution to the equation x*A = B, if it exists.

If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations x*A = B.
```

Comment: Why not just take the transpose of A and B and use solve with that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method using matrix inversion:**

If xA = b, so then x * A * inv(A) = b * inv(A) <=> x = b * inv(A) <=>, so in opencv you would have:

```
void mrdivide(const cv::Mat &A, const cv::Mat &b, cv::Mat &x) {
    x = b * A.inv();
}
```

However, this is not recommended due to high cost of matrix inversion and from numerical methodology point of view, loss of accuracy. Furthermore, it can solve only system of linear equations which is not overdefined and system matrix A must be invertible.

**Methods using matrix transposition:**

Since we have xA = b, so (xA)^T = b^T <=> A^T * x^T = b^T, so we can use cv::solve(A.t(), b.t(), x), and x.t() is an result:

```
void mrdivide(const cv::Mat &A, const cv::Mat &b, cv::Mat &x) {
     cv::solve(A.t(), b.t(), x);
     cv::transpose(x,x);
}
```

This is general and recommended solution. It provides all functionality that solve() does.

Comment: But it will fail if A is not invertible (singlarity).

Comment: Your solution based on transpose is much better than the solution based on inverse. First, inverting matrix is more complicate task than solving system of equations. Second, numerical stability of inversion is not that good.

Comment: in c++, the line x.t() does nothing. it should be transpose(x,x); or  x = x.t();

Comment: @vipers36 you're right, changed the answer. Thanks!